# Como inserir uma instrução no array só se ela for verdadeira?

Tags: php, array, string, variáveis

Eu preciso de alguma forma verificar se existe algum elemento dentro de um determinado `array` e se existir, colocar toda uma `string` num lugar especifo. Por exemplo:

> **Preciso verificar se `$categoria` não está vazia**

```
$categoria = array($values);
```

> **E depois de verificar que não está vazia, inserir a string abaixo dentro de `filter`**

```
$categoria = " 'Categoria' => array($values) ";
```

O `array` é este e tenho que inserir estas instruções dentro do filter:

```
$dados = array (
    'fields' => array(
        'ImoCodigo', 
        'Categoria', 
        'Bairro',
        'ValorVenda', 
        'Dormitorios', 
        'Vagas', 
        'FotoDestaque'
    ),
    'filter' => array(
        // As strings devem ser inseridas exatamente aqui separadas por vírgula
    ),
    'paginacao' => array(
        'pagina' => 1,
        'quantidade' => 50
    )   
);
```

> **O resultado final seria parecido com isto:**

```
...
'filter' => array(
    'Categoria' => array($values),
    'Cidade' => array($cidades),
    'ValorVenda' => array($preco)
),
...
```

Comment: `$dados['filter'][] = $categoria`, já que categoria é string. Eu faço isso pra gerar JSON e dá certo. tenta aí. Se não der certo, usa `array_push()`. Docs da função: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php

Comment: Caro @EduardoAlmeida é exatamente para isso que estou usando :)

Comment: Caro @EduardoAlmeida pode montar uma resposta mostrando a façanha por favor :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verifica se o valor não está vazio. Caso esteja vazio, seta como null.

Exemplo de como adicionar no índice `filter` do array `$dados`:

```
'filter' => array(
    'categoria' => ((!empty($values))? array($values) : null)
),
```

Mas parece estranho atribuir $values como um array `array($values)`. Isso está certo mesmo? Estará apenas criando espaço desnecessário na memória.

Caso não queira o índice `categoria` quando estiver vazio, faça a seguinte lógica:

Crie o array `$dados` normalmente, porém, sem o índice "filter"

```
$dados = array (
 ....
);
```

Com o array criado, basta adicionar ou remover os índices como quiser:

```
((!empty($values))? $dados['filter']['categoria'] = array($values) : '');
```

Exemplo completo:

```
$dados = array (
    'fields' => array(
        'ImoCodigo', 
        'Categoria', 
        'Bairro',
        'ValorVenda', 
        'Dormitorios', 
        'Vagas', 
        'FotoDestaque'
    ),
    'paginacao' => array(
        'pagina' => 1,
        'quantidade' => 50
    )   
);
((!empty($values))? $dados['filter']['categoria'] = array($values) : '');
```

Comment: Caro @Daniel se o campo estiver vazio, `categoria` não pode aparecer alí.

Comment: A resposta original era o suficiente. Bastava entender e implementar para o seu caso. Mas editei com um exemplo para o seu caso específico.

Comment: não me pergunte como adicionar $cidade e $valorVenda, que aí te dou um negativo.. rsrsrs.. basta seguir a mesma lógica.

Comment: Se observar nessa página http://new.pier36imoveis.com.br/teste.php vai reparar este output: `"Casa","Apartamento"` ... pode me ajudar a ter exatamente essa saída de `$values` ... Grato, estou aprendendo, obrigado pela paciência.

Comment: As instruções aí acima. O restante, como implementar, é a sua responsabilidade.

Comment: Obrigado por demonstrar que `arrays` podem ser importadas dentro de outras `arrays` ... isso vai me ajudar muito.